# Increment Character based on count in array

Tags: objective-c

What i am trying to do is use the alphabet for a name. In my app i have a project and the user can create a new one, at the moment the name increments as 001, 002 and so on. I use the project count to increment the name. Now what i need to do is have the project name increment as A, B, C and so on also once we hit say 11, the name would be AA. Im still fairly new to objective-c and i just need pointing in the right direction so any help would be greatly appreciated.

What i have so far is four formats for the user to have as the project name, i store what option the user has in NSUserDefaults and then user a switch statement during the project creation, i have included the switch statement below and case 4 will be the alphabetical name. Again thank you for any help.

```
NSNumber *samplePointCode = [Defaults objectForKey:@"defaultCode"];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

NSNumber *baseNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[_Lefty.arrayOfSamplePoints count] + 1];

NSString *numberWithFormat;

switch ([samplePointCode intValue]) {
    case 1:

        [formatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
        [formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
        [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:3];

        numberWithFormat = [formatter stringFromNumber:baseNumber];

        newSamplePoint.name = numberWithFormat;
        break;
    case 2:

        [formatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
        [formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
        [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:2];

        numberWithFormat = [formatter stringFromNumber:baseNumber];

        newSamplePoint.name = numberWithFormat;
        break;
    case 3:
        [formatter setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadBeforePrefix];
        [formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
        [formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];

        numberWithFormat = [formatter stringFromNumber:baseNumber];

        newSamplePoint.name = numberWithFormat;
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Updated with what i have so far.

```
        for (char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++)
        {
            [alphabet addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", a]];
        }



        NSString *letter = [alphabet objectAtIndex:[baseNumber integerValue] - 1];

        newSamplePoint.name = letter;
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do; wouldn't it make more sense to use hexidecimal representations of letters?

Comment: im not sure how i would do that, ive updated my question with the code i have so far. I have to add each letter to an array and then depending on the projects count i get the letter that matches up in the array.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a full project name would ideally look like?

Comment: at the moment there just numbers based on the count returned as there added to an array. so for example the numbers 11, 12, 21, 22 when converted to there corresponding letter in the alphabet would be AA AB BA BB. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you're saying for a name like `foobar` it would be `162525121128`? And what about lowercase letters vs. uppercase? how would you distinguish `a` from `A`?